# Infinite loop while using ?: condition inside "for" loop

Tags: javascript

These are the two examples to compare the difference:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1 < 2 ? 1 : 2; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

It will log:

> 1 2 3 ... 1000 2000 3000 ...

```js
for (var i = 0; i < (1 < 2 ? 1 : 2); i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

It will log:

> 0

My question: What is the difference between

```
i < 1 < 2 ? 1 : 2
```

and

```
i < (1 < 2 ? 1 : 2)
```

P/S: If you're using Chrome to view this question, please pressing `Shift + Esc` to open Chrome Task Manager to force to stop running the script in this page (If it doesn't stop after clicking *Run code snippet*).

Thank you!

Comment: A rule of thumb: if you need to hold and think for a second about in what order operators will evaluate; or even check the documentation page about it - just put parentheses explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first loop is being evaluated as this:

```js
for (var i = 0; (i < 1) < 2 ? 1 : 2; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i > 100) break;  // added to stop the infinite loop
}
```

The expression `(i < 1)` will be `true`, or `1`, when `i=0`.  For values of `i >= 0`, the expression `(i < 1)` will be false, which will be implicitly converted to `0`.  For all values of `i`, the inequality `(i < 1) < 2` will evaluate to true, so the value `1` will be the output of the ternary expression.  Actually, it doesn't even matter whether `(i < 1) < 2` is true or false, because the outcomes are 1 and 2, both of which are truthy.  So, your loop is basically equivalent to the following:

```
for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

That is, it just boils down to an infinite loop in `i`.

In the demo above, I added a `break` statement to the loop to prevent it from crashing your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in [JavaScript's operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Per that list, the `<` operator is higher precedence than the `?:` conditional operator, and `<` has left-to-right associativity, so `i < 1 < 2 ? 1 : 2` is interpreted as `((i < 1) < 2) ? 1 : 2`.

Immediately, you can see that it doesn't matter what the `<` conditions resolve to; the only possible results are `1` and `2`, both of which are "truthy".

For completeness, `i < 1` produces `true` for `i==0`, and `false` for `i>0`, which when used in numeric context, has a value of `1` or `0` respectively, but since both `1 < 2` and `0 < 2` both reliably produce `true`, the whole expression is always evaluating to `1`.

Comment: I get it! Thank you so much!